# How to disable that a key interrupts the autorepeat of another key?

Tags: x11, keyboard, input, xinput, autorepeat

in order to really play (vi)tetris in the terminal (:P) i want to be able to hold a key and press another without the second key interrupting the autorepeat of the first one.

example:
i will hold 'e' and at some point i will press 'x', **WITHOUT** releasing the 'e' key:

```
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeex
```

the output of what i want, would look like this:

```
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeexeeeeeeeeeeee (....)
```

using xfce4-terminal but i'm certain that i doesn't matter, because it's the same in any program that uses 'regular' keyboard input. Dedicated tetris programs like nullpomino work in the expected way of course.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the cheapest way to achieve this is to patch the terminal application so that it reads raw keyboard events. No, I'm not doing it for you, 0_0.